# How to fix data getting loaded into a single column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/voting-records/house-votes-84.data'

dataset2 = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, dtype=str)
v = dataset2.values

f = pd.factorize(v.ravel())[0].reshape(v.shape)

dataset1 = pd.DataFrame(f)
df = dataset1.astype('str')

dataset = df.values.tolist()
print (type (dataset))
print (type (dataset[1]))
print (type (dataset[1][1]))
```

The target is to transfer all the dataset into values from `1..n` for each different distinct value in dataset and afterwards to transform it into list of lists where each element is string.
The above code works great. However when I change the dataset into:

```
file_path ='https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/undocumented/connectionist-bench/vowel/vowel-context.data'
```

I get error. How can it work for this dataset as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the data you're working with. A quick print call would've helped you realise the delimiters with this one are different.

Furthermore, it appears to be numeric data; you don't need an `str` conversion anymore.

```
file_path = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/undocumented/connectionist-bench/vowel/vowel-context.data'

t = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
v = t.values
f = pd.factorize(v.ravel())[0].reshape(v.shape)

df = pd.DataFrame(f)
```

---

If you want pandas to guess the delimiter format, you might employ the use of `sep=None`:

```
t = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep=None)
```

I don't recommend this because it is very easy for pandas to make mistakes when loading your data with an inferred delimiter.

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. Is there a way to generalize the code that it will work for both types of delimiters?

Comment: @Avi You might try `pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None, sep=None)` and pandas will try to _infer_ the format, but _I don't recommend it_ because pandas seldom does a good job parsing the columns.